# USB Shortcut Icon (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, usb, icons

I want to create some shortcuts on my USB drive with my own icons.
Because not every device I use assigns the same drive letter to my usb something like `"IconFile=D:\bin\myicon.ico"` does not work.

**System Icons**

When I use system icons with a environment variable it works on all PCs.
But I want to use my own Icons.

```
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll
```

And other Environment Variables dont get evaluated correctly.

```
IconFile=%PATH%\bin\myicon.ico
```

**Save Icons on the PC**

I could save my Icons on the PC and refer to this static path. Problem is this should also work when I change PC (school/work)

**Website**

I also tried to load the icons from a Website. Which does only result in the icon showing my google chrome icon.

```
IconFile=https://mywebsite/myicon.ico
```

**WebDav**

Even trying to serve my Icon over WebDav to emulate native like behaveyour did not work.

```
IconFile=https://mywebsite/webdav/myicon.ico
or
IconFile=davs://mywebsite/webdav/myicon.ico
```

**Fallbacks**

I tryed to define something like fallback Icons but that does not work either:

```
IconFile=A:\bin\myicon.ico
IconFile=B:\bin\myicon.ico
IconFile=C:\bin\myicon.ico
IconFile=D:\bin\myicon.ico
IconFile=E:\bin\myicon.ico
IconFile=F:\bin\myicon.ico
```

**Questions**

- Is there any way I can achive this?
- Is there another way to achive a similar behaviour? (Which is not blocked by my School network like exe, bat, etc.)

PS: My test.url file looks like this:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
URL=http://someurl/
IconIndex=0
HotKey=0
IconFile=D:\bin\myicon.ico
```

Comment: Have you tried setting IconFile to *.\myicon.ico*?  I would try this on a shortcut that already works, and make sure the icon and shortcut are in the same folder.

Comment: `IconFile=%PATH%\bin\myicon.ico` doesn't make sense. `%PATH%` is a string consisting of multiple semicolon-separated paths. It's not a proper path to a single directory. Adding `\bin\myicon.ico` at the end still doesn't make it a proper path.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tested the relative Path `IconFile=.\pictures.ico` but it also does not show an icon.

Comment: @Gonios - So an icon is only being displayed when the full path to the file is provided?